# Can you use Regular Expression to Conditionally display an Image Element in a Screen Flow?

Tags: regular-expressions, spring-20, screen-flow

I'm working on a screen flow for collecting payment information. I am currently validating card info based on the digits using **REGEX**, and would like to use the same formula to conditionally display a an the **Display Image Input Element**. Does anyone know if you can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should work. Create a Formula Resource in Flow and reference it in the Set Component Visibility section of the Display Image component

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_resources_formula.htm#!